# iTunes won't back up bc it's corrupt or incompatible

Tags: itunes, backup, iphone, windows

I can't back up my iPhone to iTunes and haven't been able to for almost a year.

I updated my phone, I've reinstalled iTunes, |I've deleted the backups existing in the preferences.

Any forum I've looked at only shows how to fix it on a Mac, and I don't have one of those.
I've got a windows machine.

Comment: Please go to Start > and type System in the search bar. You can see what version of Windows you have right there.

Comment: How do you see that your phone does not get backed up? Do you get an error message of any kind (if yes, please add this to the question)?